# AMD uProf missing CPU Profile "Assess Performance" option

Tags: profiling, amd-processor

I'm trying to get Event-Based profiling session using AMDuProf (v3.5.677) but my setup is missing the
"Assess Performance" option.

See my setup

[image]

See the screenshot from the manual (section 7.3.1)

[image]

The manual does say "Time-based" is the only supported option for Intel CPUs but I'm running on a Ryzen 5900x. [Link to manual](https://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/files/AMDuprof_Resources/User_Guide_AMD_uProf_v3.5_GA.pdf)

I'm I missing something with the install ?

The only thing that showed up for me was [this](https://community.amd.com/t5/server-gurus-discussions/amd-uprof-not-showing-performance-counters/m-p/438368) I disabled both "Hyper-V" and "Virtual Machine Platform", restarted and still did not see "Assess Performance"

Comment: Hi! Did you found anything? I have same problem.

Comment: Btw, I managed to collect profile data using their CLI. For example, `AMDuProfCli collect --config assess -o profile_res .\cpu_vs_gpu.exe MT --bench`. Resulting folder can be imported into GUI.